# About how long does a headliner last?

Tags: interior

Assuming a vehicle is kept outside, about how long does a headliner typically last?

What if the vehicle is kept in a garage?

Comment: This is a really subjective question. It really depends on the car, how much someone touches it, plus the inside/outside you mention already. Any answer you get is going to be fraught with opinion. At least I've never seen a "standard" on this (nor even a rule of thumb).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks. Recently, I spoke with a vehicle upholstery expert, and he stated 10-12 years.  I had never heard that (or experienced that), so I thought I would post here for a good answer.  I have a vehicle on which the headliner is suddenly coming down, and there is rust on the roof, so I'm wondering if it's related, or if it's just a coincidence due to the age of the vehicle (the vehicle is over 15 years old).  If it's related to water instrusion, insurance will cover it; if it's normal for a headliner to only last 10-12 years, then they will not cover it.

Comment: There's no one answer to this question as it depends on the quality of the materials and workmanship that went into the car in the first place. On a quality car the headliner will last decades, on a Yugo the headliner often fell down before the car left the factory.

Comment: I worked with car upholsterers and depending on the car the way the materials are fitted makes Huge difference - if the glue is cheap and affected by moisture then they can start to fail after 2 or 3 years (depends on the country -humidity levels etc) but if the materials are high quality then, for example, my car is 14 years old and no problems...

Comment: The upholsterer would know much better than I would. The 10-12 years seems reasonable for your average vehicle (mid level car). If you had water intrusion, you'd notice it other places, most likely wet carpets or seats. There are ways of fixing a headliner which you can do at home. You can also get a whole new headliner card with the fabric already glued to it.

Comment: the ones i've had fall had a fiberboard shell with fabric glued to it, and it was the glue that failed ( i.e. you don't see the metal roof and rust doesn't enter into it..) @RockPaperLizard you may want to say what specific vehicle, sometimes there are common known problems.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 wrote "You can also get a whole new headliner card with the fabric already glued to it."  I didn't know that!  From where?  It's a Jeep Cherokee XJ.

Comment: I've found them for [Camaro's](https://www.speedwaymotors.com/PUI-82FHT-Headliner-Kit-for-1982-92-Camaro-T-Top,121894.html?sku=92616997), I don't know if they are available for your Jeep. We had to put our own fabric on my son's Cherokee when he owned it. You can get the fabric at the larger fabric shops. Use 3M adhesive to make it stick.

Comment: It was always my father's hypothesis that heat + wind will tear them down. So if your A/C breaks you drive with the windows down to bear it but the heat somehow deteriorates the headliner glue. YMMV

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 After doing more research, I've found that there are specific headliner adhesives (I think 3M makes one).  I'm not sure what makes them special, but anecdotal reports suggest that they actually work better than general-purpose spray adhesives.

Comment: Sounds about right. I found when using the adhesives, if you coat both the base and the material separately, then stick them together, you get a lot better adhesion. If the material is light, it's no big deal. if it's heavier (I used a vinyl once), this works really well to keep it in place.

Answer (score 3):

As long as it doesn't get too grubby or suffer from damp etc it should easily last the lifetime of the vehicle. I have a 21 year old Nissan that's kept outside on the drive in the UK, & the headlining in that still looks like new.